# Custom objects fields in email template

Tags: apex, salesforcedx

I would like to send an email with a template with data that comes from a custom object. I saw that with the setTargetObjectId one must use contact leads or user but me instead I used a custom object so impossible to send the mail.
If you have a solution to overcome this situation

Comment: Are you using standard email or enhanced email (with EmailMessage object)? Are you in Lightning or Classic?

Comment: Im in Lightning and i use standard email

Answer (score 1):

Use `setWhatId` to specify the custom object to use as the base merge object. Use `setTargetObjectId` to specify the User or Contact to send the email to. You can use both on the same `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` object.

Comment: Thank you for your interest
I already know this, the problem is that the contacts are not in the contact object but in a custom object

Comment: @KhadimRassoulNDEYE You would still use `setWhatId` to specify the target for merge fields, but you'll have to send the email by email address (`setToAddresses`).

Comment: @KhadimRassoulNDEYE Alternatively, if you're trying to say that you want to use the custom object as a "contact"--you can't. Only User, Lead, and Contact records may be set by `setTargetObjectId`. This is why Salesforce advises that you don't try to build custom "contact" objects, because of limitations like this one.

Comment: that's the problem, the admins used a custom contact object, thank you that even